# Is it cause for concern if an edge seal is missing from my car roof?

Tags: water, insulation

On my car roof, the edge seal is missing from one side:

[image: Missing edge seal]

This is the other side for comparison:

[image: Normal edge seal]

I live in a country where it rains but never snows. Is this something to worry about?

Comment: Both sides look the same to me.

Comment: To my knowledge the part which goes on top of there is for the most part just there for aesthetics, And ... did you put the same image in there twice?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Oops, I fixed it.

Comment: @jwh20, you're right, I updated the image.

Comment: Still, it's just a beauty strip. Not going to leak if that's what you're worried about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. If you want, you can seal that shown hairline crack with a paint repair stick to prevent water ingress. Nail polish should also do the trick